# How to remember state in a button in a C# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

A simple website application on Visual Studio. I've made a button in the design. I want it to change every time I click it, but it only changes once. can someone please help me fix it? Here's the code.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    bool click = false;
    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        click = !click;
        if (click == true)
            butt.Text = "you clicked me!";
        else
            button.Text = "Click me again!";

    }
}
```

It changes to `"you clicked me!"` and doesn't change after that.

Answer (score 2):

Every request to server is a new request. Page re-instantiates on every request to server, so your variable initializes as `false` all the time.

You should keep it at client side. You can use [`ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) to achieve this in `asp.net`:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (ViewState.Contains("click") && ViewState["click"] == false)
    {
        ViewState["click"] = true;
        butt.Text = "you clicked me!";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["click"] = false;
        button.Text = "Click me again!";
    }
}
```